# Base method is being called instead of derive method from constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was expecting derived method `get()` will be called from constructor of A. Wondering why is this not happening?

Method `get()` is virtual in base class so derive class `B` will override this method.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
protected:

    virtual int get() {
        cout<<" in A::get "<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
public:
    A() {
        get();
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B():A() {}

protected:  
    int get() override{
        cout<<"in B:get() "<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
};


int main() {
A *a;  a = new B();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While it's possible and sometimes a good choice, it's most of the time a bad idea to call virtual functions in a constructor. Only do this if you really understand what that means. The same applies for calling virtual functions in destructors.

When the instance of class `B` is constructed, it first constructs an `A`. During this phase, the object is only identified as an instance of `A` rather than `B`. So at that time, the object has a virtual function table of class `A`. This means that every virtual function call will resolve to functions of class `A` (or super classes); the same rules apply as if you would only construct an instance of `A`.

For a full explanation, please read [When my base class's constructor calls a virtual function on its this object, why doesn't my derived class's override of that virtual function get invoked?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/calling-virtuals-from-ctors.html)

Even if it was possible to call the function `B::get()` within the constructor of `A` (example: http://ideone.com/sF3411), that would be undefined behavior, since when the constructor of `A` is executed, the `this` pointer is not yet pointing to an instance of `B`, it's only "in preparation" if you will. The linked code might work, but it's a hack and exposes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the C++ FAQ link from leemes, C++ standard prevent it to be called, I will quote the standard.

The following says that, virtual member functions can be called within constructor/destructor, but they act as "not virtual", which you already know in the C++ FAQ.

> Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called
>   during construction or destruction (12.6.2). When a virtual function
>   is called directly or indirectly from a constructor or from a
>   destructor, including during the construction or destruction of the
>   class’s non-static data members, and the object to which the call
>   applies is the object (call it x) under construction or destruction,
>   the function called is the final overrider in the constructor’s or
>   destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class.
>   If the virtual function call uses an explicit class member access
>   (5.2.5) and the object expression refers to the complete object of x
>   or one of that object’s base class subobjects but not x or one of its
>   base class subobjects, the behavior is undefined.

It actually also says that, when calling virtual function from a pointer (to itself) with a type that is not direct base class of itself (in multiple inheritance), the behaviour is undefined.

Example (from standard)

```
struct V {
  virtual void f();
  virtual void g();
};
struct A : virtual V {
  virtual void f();
};
struct B : virtual V {
  virtual void g();
  B(V*, A*);
};
struct D : A, B {
  virtual void f();
  virtual void g();
  D() : B((A*)this, this) { }
};
B::B(V* v, A* a) {
  f(); // calls V::f, not A::f
  g(); // calls B::g, not D::g
  v->g(); // v is base of B, the call is well-defined, calls B::g
  a->f(); // undefined behavior, a’s type not a base of B
}
```

The above rules apply to other dynamic binding stuff, including typeid, meaning that you can't use typeid to differentiate derived class type in base constructor.

> The typeid operator (5.2.8) can be used during construction or
>   destruction (12.6.2). When typeid is used in a constructor (including
>   the mem-initializer or brace-or-equal-initializer for a non-static
>   data member) or in a destructor, or used in a function called
>   (directly or indirectly) from a constructor or destructor, if the
>   operand of typeid refers to the object under construction or
>   destruction, typeid yields the std::type_info object representing the
>   constructor or destructor’s class. If the operand of typeid refers to
>   the object under construction or destruction and the static type of
>   the operand is neither the constructor or destructor’s class nor one
>   of its bases, the result of typeid is undefined.